# Cancel a form to be submitted, do not change the data of the entity

Tags: javascript, python, forms

I have a div

```
   <div id="updateChoice%s" class="text-center"></div>
```

which shows a the following upon a "updateText" button is clicked

```
function updateText(urlsafe) {
    document.getElementById("updateChoice"+urlsafe).innerHTML +=
    '<br><br><form id="dynForm" action="/updateText" method="post" >' +
   '<textarea name="newContent" rows="5" cols="80"></textarea>' + 
   '<input type="hidden" name="update" value=' + urlsafe + '>' +   '<br><br>' + 
   '<input class="choice" type="submit" value="Submit"></input> <button class="choice"  onclick="cancelUpdate('+ urlsafe +')">Cancel</button>' +
   '</form>';
}
```

I want to cancel the updating of the text but it doesn't work unless "newContent" is empty, here is /updateText file and cancelUpdate(urlsafe)

/updateText:

```
class UpdateText(webapp2.RequestHandler):
     def post(self):
         greeting_key = ndb.Key(urlsafe=self.request.get('update'))
         event = greeting_key.get(); 
         if(self.request.get('newContent') != ''):
           event.content = self.request.get('newContent');
           event.put();
         self.redirect('/events');
```

cancelUpdate(urlsafe):

```
function cancelUpdate(urlsafe) {
    document.getElementByName("newContent").innerHTML="";
    document.getElementById("dynForm").submit();
}
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **/updateText handler** remains on not updating the text if upon submission it is empty, so do not change anything:

In the **cancelUpdate(urlsafe) function**, use this aproach:

```
function cancelUpdate(urlsafe) {
       document.getElementById("updateChoice"+urlsafe).innerHTML = "";
}
```

Add \' to the parameter urlsafe as you pass it and not ". So here is correct javascript function call to div#updateChoice%s is:

```
function updateText(urlsafe) {
    document.getElementById("updateChoice"+urlsafe).innerHTML =
    '<br><br><form id="dynForm" action="/updateText" method="post" >' +
   '<textarea name="newContent" rows="5" cols="80"></textarea>' + 
   '<input type="hidden" name="update" value=' + urlsafe + '>' +   '<br><br>' + 
   '<input class="choice" type="submit" value="Submit"></input><button type="button" class="choice" onClick="cancelUpdate(\''+ urlsafe +'\')">Cancel</button>' +
   '</form>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very difficult to understand (What do you mean by "cancel the updating of the text"? What did you expect to happen? What exactly "doesn't work"?).

Also, there are **multiple** issues with the code you provided (none of which have to do anything with GAE, Python or webapp2), here are a few that might be helpful to resolve your issue:

1) Your `cancelUpdate` function accepts a `urlsafe` parameter but is not using it.

2) In your `cancelUpdate` function you're using a non-existing function `getElementByName`, you probably meant to use its plural version [`getElementsByName()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp)

3)

- On the same `document.getElementByName("newContent").innerHTML="";` line you are retreiving an element with the name `newContent` which is a `<textarea>` element and are attempting to empty its `innerHTML` property, but a `<textarea>` doesn't have one. If you want to empty a `<textarea>`'s contents - you need to do `document.getElementByName("newContent").value="";` instead.
- Since your `cancelUpdate` function has an unused parameter `urlsafe` and although it's not clear what your issue is but since in your `updateText` function you are creating an element with `id="updateChoice"+urlsafe` and assuming that when you hit cancel - you also want to destroy that form, then your `cancelUpdate` would look as simple as this:

```
    function cancelUpdate(urlsafe) {
        document.getElementById("updateChoice"+urlsafe).innerHTML = "";
    }
```

4)

- Your "Cancel" button doesn't have a `type` specified which means it will default to `submit` even when you don't want to submit the form so you need to add `type="button"` to prevent the submission.
- You are calling `document.getElementById("dynForm").submit();` in your `cancelUpdate` function which in the combination with the previous issue will submit your form twice.